# Significato di "eserzione"

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Furto della Cassa Comunale, contenente somme vigenti, parte innumerario, parte in fede di 
>   credito; saccheggio in diverse case civili con appropriazione di somme, fede di credito, gioje, oggetti d'oro e di argento accompagnato da incendî di libri creditorî e di ogni documento appartenente a fortune private; devastazione a frutta, a ricolta, nei campi estesa e generalizzata per **eserzione** degli anarchisti; appropriazione di case, e di poderi precedentemente per sentenza pendente; o volontariamente, e per atti autentici o laicali, scrocco di somme per componende, e minacce di danno, o di vita, arresti arbitrarii, ed ogni altra abusiva escandescenza, e tutto questo iniziato al grido di Viva Vittorio Emmanuele - Viva Garibaldi, e all'ombra del Vessillo della rigenerazione, che aveva servito di mezzo a disarmare preventivamente, ed agglomerare vittorie designate; come le prime ad essere immolate, e che dovevan essere seguite da altre, cui fortuite circostanze trovarono, e che dovevano formare i prodromi di un numero di reati e di scelleraggini, poscia parte consumati, parte per divina misericordia non commessi.

Si tratta di parte di un documento emesso dalla     Commissione Speciale di Patti  nel 1860.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato del termine "eserzione" che appare in questo testo? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario, ma invece su Google Books ci sono parecchie occorrenze, soprattutto in libri dell'Ottocento.

Comment: Ho trovato il termine [eserzione](http://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/do/gazzetta/downloadPdf;jsessionid=PZ2-qXhOR-XGCIb-w5ZAUQ__.ntc-as2-guri2a?dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=20140418&numeroGazzetta=91&tipoSerie=SG&tipoSupplemento=GU&numeroSupplemento=0&numPagina=34&estensione=pdf&edizione=0) in relazione alla crescita del grano e delle pannocchie. Potrebbe essere un riferimento al fatto che sono stati devastati i campi di grano e soprattutto mais, effettuando l’eserzione delle pannocchie non ancora mature, quindi strappandole dalla pianta.

Comment: Nel documento che hai trovato vedo che si usa l'aggettivo "[eserto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eserto)" che, secondo il Treccani, significa: «In botanica, di stame o stilo che sporge più o meno fuori del tubo corollino o perigoniale.» Inoltre è interessante vedere che deriva dal latino *exserĕre* che significa «mettere fuori».

Answer (score 1):

Sospetto che qui *eserzione* sia collegato al latino [*exerceo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exerceo) (cfr. l'inglese *exertion*) e all'italiano [*esercire*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esercire/):

> **eṡercire** (ant. **eṡercére**) v. tr. [dal lat. *exercere* «esercitare», comp. di *ex-* e *arcere* nel sign. di «mettere in movimento»] (*io eṡercisco*, *tu eṡercisci*, ecc.), non com. – Attendere a un mestiere, esercitare un’attività, e più in partic. condurre, amministrare un negozio o un’impresa.

In questo caso parafraserei l'espressione con *ad opera*, vale a dire

> devastazione a frutta, a ricolta, nei campi estesa e generalizzata **ad opera** degli anarchisti

Comment: Quindi, "eserzione" sarebbe più o meno un sinonimo di "esecuzione"... Questo avrebbe anche senso [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=BG61D8oaUlYC&pg=PA604&dq=eserzione&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicyZuUzuzbAhWnKMAKHZH-CQMQ6AEINzAJ#v=onepage&q=eserzione&f=false) e [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=bt8YAQAAIAAJ&q=eserzione&dq=eserzione&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizvty63-7bAhWhAcAKHelUBn8Q6AEIKzAG).

Comment: @Charo Sono abbastanza certo di quest'interpretazione. Si tratta ad ogni modo di una parola *estremamente* desueta, ma nel contesto del brano che riporti ha senso che venga usata. Nota che *exerceo* ha avuto come riflesso italiano più comune la parola *esercizio* (e.g. *l'esercizio di un'attività*)